# How to get select position in SINGLE_CHOISE_LIST when OK button pressed?

Tags: android, android-widget

How I can get the position of select item in the list. I am using below code. I am getting `int whichButton` when OK button pressed. But it always show -1

```
private void filterByLocationDialog(final String[] items){
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(PictureCollectionActivity.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("Select a Location")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Toast.makeText(PictureCollectionActivity.this, "Now"+whichButton, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
            }
        })
       .create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you want is the `whichButton` in the `OnClickListener` in `setSingleChoiceItems` (the list of choices).

The problem is, how to keep track of it. There might be more elegant solutions but this works:

```
    final int[] selected = new int[1];
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Select a Location")
            .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {

                            selected[0] = whichButton;
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Toast.makeText(WeightTestActivity.this,
                            "Now" + selected[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                        }
                    }).create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: humm, I was thinking in the same way. Thanks for your time